# HMAC / Javascript - where to store the secret?

Tags: javascript, hmac

The client gets it's secret for HMAC encryption after it's first login on the server - but what's the best way to store the secret on the (java-script) client? cookie, localStorage?
thx

Comment: Isn't hmac is a hash computing via key ?  its not an encrypted value. but a hash of data by a key...(an p.s  - i would go with cookie.). localStorage is not for that thing.

Comment: It's a combination of a public and a private key. Public key to identify a user and a private key to generate a hash over the data being transferred.

Comment: You shouldn't pass the private key from the server to the client over the write, that makes it highly insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer is, it depends. `localStorage` and cookies are not equivalent. Although they both can be used to store information on the client, they serve very specific goals. `localStorage` is meant to store application's data locally. It cannot be set directly from the server and is not sent to the server through HTTP headers either.

*You may also have a look at [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage)*.

However, cookies are typically created from the server (even if there's a JS API) through HTTP headers and they contain expiry information. Once set, they will be part of every client request's HTTP headers, allowing the server to access the information.

Both ways are probably equally secure since they both cannot be accessed from another domain. However if you are transmitting secure information you should probably do it through [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `best` way is pretty subjective.

If you must store it on the client (you must, I assume), then it can't be secure, it just can't.
Putting that aside, the `best` way depends on your situation.

Are you trying to target older browsers? Then you can't use local storage.

Since we've already removed security from the equation, your most far-reaching, cross-browser-compatible solution is to store it in a cookie.
That's also probably one of the easiest solutions, though certainly the least secure (since your only form of security here is obscurity, and cookies are... not obscure).

Comment: Your second question first - no, older browsers are not supported.
For a JS-Application (with REST backend) ,if I am right, I have to store it on the client. The secret should be only transferred once - after the first login. (Or if the key becomes invalid)

Comment: If you aren't trying to explicitely hiding this information from the current client, but simply from others we can probably say it's secure. You cannot access cookies/localStorage from another domain.